# Itextsharp not creating new blank page when loop is at the end of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am opening a pdf template and creating a new pdf and write on it. On the loop I have to enter dynamic data from a list, I am subtracting the height variable to put one item after the other vertically. My issue is that when the list is too long and is approaching the end of the pdf page the code is not creating a new blank page to continue writing the rest items of the list. However, it is overwriting the rest items one above the other in last item of the page.  I have try to increase my height variable but still the code is not working to produce new page.

```
string pdfpath = context.Server.MapPath(@"~/mypdf_new.pdf");
string oldFile = context.Server.MapPath(@"~/mypdftemplate.pdf");
string newFile = pdfpath;                

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);

Document document = new Document(size);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

document.Open();

string myFont = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), 
     "Calibri.TTF");

iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont bfR;
bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(myFont,
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

BaseFont title = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font titleFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(title, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

int myheight = 500;
foreach (var mypro in listofproducts)
{
    ColumnText ct26 = new ColumnText(cb);
    Phrase myText26 = new Phrase(mypro.ProductCode, titleFont);
    ct26.SetSimpleColumn(myText26, 60, myheight, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    ct26.Go();

    ColumnText ct28 = new ColumnText(cb);
    Phrase myText28 = new Phrase(Convert.ToString(mypro.quantity), titleFont);
    ct28.SetSimpleColumn(myText28, 340, myheight, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    ct28.Go();

    myheight = myheight - 20;
  }

  PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
  cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

  document.Close();
  fs.Close();
  writer.Close();
  reader.Close();
```

Comment: format your code

Comment: And also: why are you using an old version of iText? The current version is iText 7, and by the looks of your code, you're using iText 5 or earlier.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use `ColumnText`? It looks like you could simply achieve your goal by adding the `Phrase` instances in `Paragraph` instances to your `document`, probably after setting margins accordingly...

Comment: I have try to add phrase but the text i display is dynamic and i had some strange results on adjust the text on standard positions. this is the only reason a choose column text. If you have to suggest idea with phrase i am open to give a try